# Developer ID signed apps cannot load external data under macOS Sierra

Tags: download, certificate, signed, macos-sierra

We currently have problems with the download versions (ZIP) of our applications under the new operating system MacOS Sierra from Apple. It is a (non-native) video tutorial app with external data and different startfiles (certificate signed) for Mac and Windows (originally created for DVDs).

Although the Mac startfile of the download version was properly signed with a valid Apple Developer ID certificate, an authorization problem now appears and the application can no longer load external data. The same application on DVD still works impeccably.

My researches have shown that under "macOS Sierra" developer ID signed apps (outside the App Store) are not allowed to use external libraries, external code or external data:

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/MacOSX/WhatsNewInOSX/Articles/OSXv10.html

> Starting in macOS 10.12, you can not get any longer. An app distributed outside the Mac App. To provide secure execution, code your disk image is using the codesign tool, or distribute your app through the Mac App Store. For more information, see the updated revision to macOS Code Signing In Depth.

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2206/_index.html

Is our described type of application no longer compatible with macOS Sierra?

Is there any solution to continue offering our applications as a download for macOS Sierra outside the App Store?
Possibly one could encapsulate here in the individual trainings over an automatism all necessary files in an app, afterwards sign and to prepare as DMG !?

Answer (score 0):

Have solved the problem.
With a signed DMG everything works again as before. This is now possible under macOS Sierra (and from Mac OS X 10.11.5.)